# RSS/XML of all Categories and/or Tags

Tags: categories, tags, rss, xml

Is it possible to get an RSS / XML feed of all WordPress Categories and/or Tags?

I've searched the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds), which was very helpful in giving examples on how to access specific, individual RSS feeds, but have not been able to find any source on how to display all Categories of a site.

Using examples from the Codex, specific Categories can be found with the following structure:

> example.com/category/categoryname/feed

I'm looking for something along the lines of:

> example.com/**category/*/feed**

OR

> example.com/**categories/feed**

Any thoughts? Solutions? Suggestions?

---

**EDIT:**
I'm not looking for a feed of posts, rather a feed of all actual categories or tags. Ideally, this feed would contain only the categories themselves, no specific post data. Using the categories in the feed, however, I'd be able to then gather posts as needed by looking at each of the categories specific RSS feeds.

An example of what I'm looking for would be a feed that returned the following list:

> - Category 1
> - Category 2
> - Category 3
> - Category 4

Iterating over that, when needed, could give me the posts for each.

Comment: What kind of category/tag info are you looking for? What about exporting .wxr files? Maybe you already got a sitemap.xml?

Comment: I dont think you will find a solution for this as a feed for all categories or tags would be the same thing in essence as just providing a feed for all your posts. Each post would be assigned to at least 1 category or have tags so this would include everything and just a normal feed would do this then...

Comment: @MattRoyal I've updated the question to help clarify. I'm not looking for a feed of posts, but for the categories themselves. No post data is needed- a feed of nothing but the actual categories used would suffice.

Comment: @birgire I'm looking for the category / tag short name. Whichever info would then allow a call to: http://example.com/category/categoryname/feed

I'll look into which sitemaps are available.

Comment: @user2242816 I added an answer with a demo plugin, that you can hopefully extend further to your needs.

Comment: @user2242816 Any progress on this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Demo plugin for JSON export:

I'm not sure the RSS feed structure suits your needs, for example taxonomies and terms   don't have any dates for the *public date* field. So here's an example how you can retrieve all the terms for a given taxonomy:

```
/** 
 * Plugin Name: WPSE - JSON export all terms for a given taxonomy. 
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/151908/26350
 * Version:     0.0.1
 */ 

add_filter( 'query_vars', function( $qv ){
    $qv[] = 'wpse-export-taxonomy';
    return $qv;
});

add_action( 'template_redirect', function(){

    $tax = get_query_var( 'export-taxonomy' );

    if( ! empty( $tax ) )
    {
        if( taxonomy_exists( $tax ) )
        {
            $data = get_terms( sanitize_key( $tax ), 
                array( 
                    'hide_empty' => true,
                    'orderby'    => 'name', 
                    'order'      => 'ASC', 
                ) 
            );

            if( count( $data ) > 0 )
                wp_send_json_success( $data );
        }
    }

    // Error:
    wp_send_json_error();

} );
```

where you can modiy the `get_terms()` arguments to your needs.

### Usage Examples:

Categories export:

```
http://example.com/?wpse-export-taxonomy=category
```

Post tags export:

```
http://example.com/?wpse-export-taxonomy=post_tag
```

Custom `country` taxonomy export:

```
http://example.com/?wpse-export-taxonomy=country
```

The category export could look like this:

```
{"success":true,"data":{
"0":{"term_id":"65","name":"animals","slug":"animals","term_group":"0","term_taxonomy_id":"75","taxonomy":"category","description":"id:65","parent":"0","count":"5"},
"1":{"term_id":"61","name":"birds","slug":"birds","term_group":"0","term_taxonomy_id":"70","taxonomy":"category","description":"id:61","parent":"65","count":"8"}
"2":{"term_id":"13","name":"falcons","slug":"falcons","term_group":"0","term_taxonomy_id":"15","taxonomy":"category","description":"id:13","parent":"61","count":"3"}
}}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Apologies for the incredibly late acceptance of this answer! While I'd been looking for an example using Wordpress's default RSS feeds (I didn't have control of actual WP instance), this is still a great solution for my question. Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome and thanks for reporting back @user2242816